# Nomes de Colunas Matriz usando R

Tags: r

Essa é a minha matriz no R:

```
n_forward=50

matriz=matrix(0,nrow=length(1:n_forward),ncol=16)
```

O numero de linhas depende do comando `n_forward`.

A partir daí quero nomear as linhas em t+1, t+2,....,t+(n_forward)

Há como fazer isso automaticamente, sem que precise fazer isso abaixo?

```
rownames(matriz)<-c("t+1","t+2","t+3","t+4","t+5","t+6","t+7","t+8","t+9","t+10","t+11","t+12","t+13","t+14","t+15","t+16","t+17","t+18","t+19","t+20","t+21","t+22","t+23","t+24","t+25","t+26","t+27","t+28","t+29","t+30", "t+31","t+32","t+33","t+34","t+35","t+36","t+37","t+38","t+39","t+40","t+41","t+42","t+43","t+44","t+45","t+46","t+47","t+48","t+49","t+50")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `paste` conjuntamente com `seq_len`.

```
rn <- paste("t", seq_len(n_forward), sep = "+")
rownames(matriz) <- rn
```

`seq_len` cria a sequencia `1, 2, ..., n_forward`. E `paste` faz o resto.
Note que não é necessário criar o vetor `rn`, basta fazer `rownames(matriz) <- paste(...)`. Eu prefiro as duas linhas para o código de uma resposta ser mais legível, nada mais.